# jQuery - setInterval/clearInterval delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm new to jQuery and am trying to fill a div over a certain amount of time. When that time is up I want to clear the div - pretty simple, right?

Summary: I click a button and the div starts filling(using `animate({ height: "100%"}, workPeriod * 1000)` over workPeriod which is 20 seconds. Once it's filled I want the div to be emptied. The div fills without issue and then once it's complete it takes about 5-10 seconds before it clears using `animate({ height: "0%"}, workPeriod * 5000)`

```
$('#begin').click(function () {
    var workPeriod = 20
    var start = new Date($.now());
    var end = new Date(start.getTime() + 1000 * workPeriod);

    var workInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var currentDif = Math.floor((new Date($.now()) - end) / 1000) * -1;
        if (currentDif < 0) {
            $('#session-time').animate({
                height: '0%'
            }, 0);
            clearInterval(workInterval);
            //I want the animation above to occur instantly but it's happening several seconds after
            //the clearInterval call
        } else {
            $('#session-time').animate({
                height: '100%'
            }, workPeriod * 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Question: How can I make the div empty immediately once it's full instead of waiting the 5-10 seconds?

btw, I'm very new to jQuery and still very much a beginner when it comes to programming so any advice will be well received

Comment: What is the question? Or you just want to share the code to community?

Comment: my fault for not making it clear. How can I make the div empty immediately rather than waiting 5-10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to call another function/animation once your animation is complete, that functionality is already built into jQuery's animate function.

[From the jQuery documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete)

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

I tried to get it to work with your code posted above, but I couldn't get your timer stuff to work. [Nevertheless, I made this codepen, to show that the animation complete function does work when your complete function is another animation.](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/KdppRg)